# What does this sequence of integral converge to?

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I am not a mathematician, I'm a chemist who happened to also be a math enthusiast.

I was playing with error function the other day, and just out of curiosity compute these integrals using Desmos. 
$$ \int _{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(x^2+x+1)} dx \approx 0.837247915445$$

Then, I just add more terms to it 
$$ \int _{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)} dx \approx 0.710530779033$$
$$ \int _{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)} dx \approx 0.682543666557$$
$$ \int _{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(x^8+x^7+x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)} dx \approx 0.671744903773$$

And so on. At 20th term (order 40 polynomial), the result is $0.655405978856$

One of the thing that I realize is the difference between terms became smaller, and I think the limit is $\frac{\pi^{0.5}}{e} \approx 0.652049332173292$. But I have no idea why, or if this is even true. 
I hope someone can provide me with what the limit is.

Comment: My guess would be that the limit is $\int_{-1}^1 e^{-1/(1-x)} dx$, which – according to Wolfram Alpha – is $\approx 0.653288$. The “dominated convergence theorem” might be needed to make this rigorous.

Comment: @MartinR that does make sense, considering that it basically $exp((x^n-1)/(x-1))$ but not sure how to connect them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The functions
$$
 f_n(x) = \exp(-(1+x+\cdots + x^{2n}) = \begin{cases}\exp\left( -\frac{x^{2n+1}-1}{x-1}\right) & \text{ if } x \ne 1 \\
\exp\bigl(-(2n+1)\bigr) & \text{ if } x = 1
\end{cases}
$$

- decrease to zero if $x \ge 1$,
- decrease to $\exp(-1/(1-x))$ if $0 \le x < 1$,
- increase to $\exp(-1/(1-x))$ if $-1 \le x \le 0$,
- decrease to zero if $x < 1$.

Therefore [Beppo Levi's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Beppo_Levi%27s_lemma) aka “monotone convergence” can be applied on the intervals $(-\infty, -1)$, $[-1, 0]$,  $[0, 1]$, and $[1, \infty)$ separately, and it follows that
$$
 \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_n(x) \,dx = \int_{-1}^1 e^{-1/(1-x)} \, dx \, .
$$

According to [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+exp%28-1%2F%281-x%29%29+from+-1+to+1) the value of that integral is
$$
Ei\left(-\frac 12\right) + \frac{2}{\sqrt e} \approx 0.653288 
$$
where $Ei(x)$ is the [exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral).

Answer (score 4):

Here is another way using the dominated convergence theorem. The integral can be expressed as
$$
    \int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\left(\dfrac{x^{2n + 1} - 1}{1 - x}\right)dx
$$
(**Small note:** Technically, we can ignore $x = 1$ since $\{1\}$ is a null set w.r.t the Lebesgue measure)

As suggested in the comments, we bound the integrand by
$$
    f(x) = \begin{cases}
        e^x, \text{ if } x \le -1\\
        1, \text{ if } x \in (-1, 1)\\
        e^{-x}, \text{ if } x \ge 1
    \end{cases}
$$
Notice that $f > 0$ and,
$$
     \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx < \infty
$$
Thus, by the dominate convergence theorem,
\begin{align*}
     \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\left(\dfrac{x^{2n + 1} - 1}{1 - x}\right)dx &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\exp\left(\dfrac{x^{2n + 1} - 1}{1 - x}\right)dx\\
 &= \int_{-1}^1 \exp\left(\dfrac{1}{x-1}\right)dx
\end{align*}

Comment: Can you explain more why the bounds of the integration changed from inf to 1?

Comment: $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \exp\left(\dfrac{x^{2n + 1} - 1}{1 - x}\right) = 0$ if $\vert x \vert > 1$ and $= \exp\left(\dfrac{1}{x - 1}\right)$ if $\vert x \vert \in (-1, 1)$. That's why the integration bounds change from $(-\infty, \infty)$ to $(-1, 1)$